# Apache beam IllegalArgumentException: Unsafe trigger may lose data

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

With the following window function,

```
Window.<KV<String, Long>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardDays(1)))
        .triggering(
                AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                    .withEarlyFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
                            .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(30)))
        )
        .accumulatingFiredPanes()
        .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(20), Window.ClosingBehavior.FIRE_IF_NON_EMPTY));
```

We meet the below error under `Beam 2.20.0`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsafe trigger may lose data, see https://s.apache.org/finishing-triggers-drop-data: AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow().withEarlyFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(1 hour))
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.GroupByKey.applicableTo(GroupByKey.java:171)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.GroupByKey.expand(GroupByKey.java:226)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.GroupByKey.expand(GroupByKey.java:110)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:542)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:476)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:355)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Combine$PerKey.expand(Combine.java:1596)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Combine$PerKey.expand(Combine.java:1485)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:542)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:493)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:368)
    at com.beam.test.monitorAdsUnit$CaculateUnitAbnormalECPM.expand(monitorAdsUnit.java:153)
    at com.beam.test.monitorAdsUnit$CaculateUnitAbnormalECPM.expand(monitorAdsUnit.java:149)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:542)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:493)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:368)
    at com.beam.test.monitorAdsUnit.main(monitorAdsUnit.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And we found fix solution from URL link above

> The fix is that for a top-level `GroupByKey` transform, triggers that finish are disallowed.

Could someone give us a more clear explanation of it?

Currently, our workaround is that implicitly add `Repeatedly.forever(...)` to top level triggers.

Answer (score 3):

Your trigger `AfterWatermark.withEarlyFirings(...)` would fire for the last time when the watermark reached the end of the window and then drop all subsequent data. Such triggers are disabled because of the near-certainty that this is data loss.

In your case, you set the allowed lateness via `.withAllowedLateness(<20 minutes>)`. I assume you do want some output that includes those 20 minutes of data. But it would always be dropped. The allowed lateness has no effect since the trigger will discard the data.

Your workaround is a correct change. It will cause late data to be emitted immediately. What I recommend for best readability is to almost always use a trigger like:

```java
AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
    .withEarlyFirings(...)
    .withLateFirings(...)
```

This clearly outlines the "lifecycle" of the aggregation: you have one behavior for early/speculative results, one clear "done" output, and then one behavior for late/revision results.

Downstream, you can observe `PaneInfo` to adjust processing for the above three cases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and we solve this issue now. We confuse `The fix is that for a top-level GroupByKey transform, triggers that finish are disallowed.`  which mentioned in the related document. Could you please figure out how to do `GroupByKey` transform?